# Is there a unix command to dump all files from each folder in the current directory?

Tags: unix

I am facing a bit of an issue. I have a over 50 directories that have weird names such as "m$829@37" that each contain one photo. They were created like that when I did a photo upload from a phone and now I have no choice but to go through each using the mouse manaully.

Is there a Unix command to dump all the photos from every folder?

Comment: Do you want to move all the files in all the directories to a single folder somewhere?  `mkdir /tmp/somewhere && mv */*.jpg /tmp/somewhere`

Comment: yes , i just want some way of extracting each photo from each directory

Comment: `cp */*.jpg /tmp/somewhere` is probably safer than `mv` .  You can also try `echo */*.jpg` to get a list of all the photo files you'd affect if you ran the command.  (If you have `.gif` or `.png` files instead, you'll have to change `jpg` appropriately.)